# Download image with URL in python: gaierror

Tags: python, url

I am trying to download an image with URL in python but unfortunately, i get an error and i have no idea how to deal with it.

I am using the following code:

```
def dowload(url_img):
    try :
        r = requests.get(url_img)
        with open('a.jpg', 'wb') as f:
           f.write(r.content)
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        print("Some Err")
    if os.path.exists("a.jpg"):
       os.remove("a.jpg")
    return img
```

The URL to image is: "http://cloudimages.youthconnect.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/539.jpg"

Problem is that i get following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1324                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1325                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1326             except OSError as err: # timeout error

16 frames
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1325                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1326             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1327                 raise URLError(err)
   1328             r = h.getresponse()
   1329         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

I can not check if i get status code **200** because the site can't be reached. When i try to open connection then at that time i get this error.

I will grateful if anyone can give some solution to this problem. The url comes from VGGface Dataset where i am trying to download images one by one.

Comment: Is the URL correct?

Comment: @IainShelvington The URL comes from VGG face Dataset so i have to go to these URLs one by one and check if they work & if they work then download image. So i don't know how to check for such URL. Normally i check the response or status code but here the situation is different.

Comment: Can you catch `URLError` to handle cases where the URL is not valid or the site no longer exists? A DNS lookup returns nothing for that domain

Comment: @IainShelvington If i can catch such exceptions then i would skip that image & return Nothing. As you can see the function takes a URL as parameter, so i have lot of URLs.

Comment: You're already catching `urllib2.HTTPError`, can you not add an additional `except` block?

Comment: @IainShelvington it's URLError so i don't know if python can catch errors as i move from Java(can only catch exceptions) & C++ to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by using simple `except:` statement as i don't need to know the type of the exception.